# Mongodb : How should I get original Json structure after filter the records based on requirement?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb.

I have a Json document in collection like :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55abf32f358e3aca807f0e6a"),
    "usercbid" : 1995492.0000000000000000,
    "defaultnotifytype" : {
        "status" : true,
        "alert" : true,
        "action" : true
    },
    "calendar" : {
        "alert" : 2468.0000000000000000,
        "action" : 13579.0000000000000000,
        "status" : 123456.0000000000000000
    },
    "assignment" : [ 
        {
            "orgid" : {
                "service" : "AVPN",
                "adminemail" : "pl9129@att.com",
                "notifytype" : {
                    "status" : true,
                    "alert" : true
                },
                "keytype" : "MCN",
                "KeyValue" : "SK1383"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "orgid" : {
                "KeyValue" : "DD3342",
                "service" : "<all>",
                "keytype" : "MCN"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "orgid" : {
                "notifytype" : {
                    "optout" : true
                },
                "keytype" : "MCN",
                "keyvalue" : "<all>",
                "service" : "MVPN"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "order" : {
                "date" : "2015-03-15",
                "adminemail" : "abc.com",
                "notifytype" : {
                    "alert" : true
                },
                "id" : 123456.0000000000000000
            }
        }, 
        {
            "order" : {
                "id" : 135246.0000000000000000,
                "date" : "2015-03-17",
                "adminemail" : "abc.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to filter above json document with following condition:

```
var result =  db.subscription.aggregate(
    [ { $unwind: "$assignment" }
      , {$match : {$or:
          [
             {
              "assignment.order.id" : 123456          
             },
             {
                       "assignment.orgid.keytype" : { $in: ["MCN"]}
                       ,"assignment.orgid.KeyValue" : { $in: ["<all>","SK1383"]}
                       ,"assignment.orgid.service" : { $in: ["<all>","AVPN"]}          
             }
          ]
        }
      }

  ,{$group: {_id: "$_id", assignment: {$push: "$assignment"}}}  
    // ,{$project : { usercbid : $usercbid, defaultnotifytype : 1, calendar : 1, assignment: 1} }

    ]
 )
printjson(result);
```

Result of above query is :

```
{
    "result" : [        
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55abf32f358e3aca807f0e6a"),
            "assignment" : [
                {
                    "orgid" : {
                        "service" : "AVPN",
                        "adminemail" : "pl9129@att.com",
                        "notifytype" : {
                            "status" : true,
                            "alert" : true
                        },
                        "keytype" : "MCN",
                        "KeyValue" : "SK1383"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "order" : {
                        "date" : "2015-03-15",
                        "adminemail" : "pl9129@att.com",
                        "notifytype" : {
                            "alert" : true
                        },
                        "id" : 123456
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

But my final result lost the following original content:

```
"usercbid" : 1995492.0000000000000000,
    "defaultnotifytype" : {
        "status" : true,
        "alert" : true,
        "action" : true
    },
    "calendar" : {
        "alert" : 2468.0000000000000000,
        "action" : 13579.0000000000000000,
        "status" : 123456.0000000000000000
    },
```

How should I append above original content with filtered records?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[$Fisrt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) is the operator which helps you getting the required output.
When you do a [$Group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), the result of the $Group pipeline operator contains only those fields which are specified inside the $Group pipeline operator.

So, from your query we can notice that you are grouping based on "_Id" and you are selecting only "assignment" key field, so the OUTPUT of this group pipeline operator will contain only those 2 fileds ( "_ID" and "assignment" ).

To make sure that the other left out feilds ( usercbid, defaultnotifytype , calendar ) to be part of the $Group pipeline output, we need to mention that explicitly in the Group pipeline using [$First](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) as below :

```
{ $group: { _id: "$_id", assignment: {$push: "$assignment"}, 
                   usercbid : { $first : "usercbid"} , 
                   defaultnotifytype : { $first : "defaultnotifytype" } , 
                   calendar : { $first : "calendar"} 
           }
}
```

**[$First](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) Returns the value that results from applying an expression to the first document in a group of documents that share the same group by key.**

Please check the below query, it will help you in fetching the required output :

```
var result =  db.subscription.aggregate(
    [   { $unwind: "$assignment" }
      , { $match : {$or:
          [
             {
              "assignment.order.id" : 123456          
             },
             {
                       "assignment.orgid.keytype" : { $in: ["MCN"]}
                       ,"assignment.orgid.KeyValue" : { $in: ["<all>","SK1383"]}
                       ,"assignment.orgid.service" : { $in: ["<all>","AVPN"]}          
             }
          ]
        }
      }

  ,{ $group: { _id: "$_id", assignment: {$push: "$assignment"}, 
               usercbid : { $first : "usercbid"} , 
               defaultnotifytype : { $first : "defaultnotifytype" } , 
               calendar : { $first : "calendar"} 
             }
   }  

    ]
 ).pretty();
```

Comment: It works well, but small correction on : usercbid : { $first : "usercbid"} -> usercbid : { $first : "$usercbid"}